# read and search in pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, encoding

I am trying to get text from pdf file with this code, but it return like below encoded text :-

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
echo $content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
fclose($fp);
```

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream xœí\Ks¹¾ûWàâ*¹<„ñ~ø*¯½›ÊVíf«*‡(ZIÌRyHZÑ¿O÷ŠIKÅªØ&9 h|Sn“TÑâ©mÐÚ å 6¨Mxø´Ê“üú•wÔ:,WP¥ˆqžzN~ƒÇ)¹zõ¯CF{Wê?¿ß$èQ‡šQ†J_`ù-ÏF‹Ë99NOsòeqw7y ðíÕx’’‹3ò™ãœ\¼YA½ÖG%°Ãå¶QO ³Rð¯Œ©8U %æåG]MÀ¥J'{±¢C¾®ÃõÂ÷^S8oQgœxÎ§ÖÊø5›§ï×ÕÙZ‚ðÔ6K ç7@‘ñõ"OgdtÎHvE$ü2Ì/oŠ.£]t~ˆ‚9vêPebí›†LLˆê³ž{ÖvÆ{OYEò”|J'ãïiþcø2ËGØ+sè«;ø5§×äÛb˜Ïa¨]œñÙœ|&ØUo6Ø”¶j¥TóF½ûsIzJÞürl¯w$Kgr­tÑAÄ9&› ÚÒƒ`T¼bÐŒÜ9ü<œÃ8úÀ¿ÇáÈ÷t6K'3¤Oâ¹HŒàdt?Ío†óRlvy“Ž“tDæùš’QÉIø}<%KÖ‘¯‹9É¦`ïW)°Ó Ì(¢hº›&XÂtÝ°¢M—Ùôjœß–mº~O¡aé4hÚþV ¨`ÂºOÏáŽ=­Àªœˆ·Ùôúâþf|yó>>wð„7ÊzCßçXì¨Lð•´.ð)E'fœMgµ&jN•.\8A ÅÑµÚGÉZPaÃ:úâØþø˜¡Þ”uˆ,‡Ì·ãépæë¹]ÌÃ ^çiz›Nç4f&`–jÓ¨å™ÓèùÚÎ)*ÊIûimãWïœ¤Ü#©v‘ŒGs*ÃJNÎxg &b5ã¹+)Ÿ§ù,Oo‡ãé&Ip­Ši,‚ó²Øf='Ç¨¡ƒ1ª•ˆ@%`&Àž J>9*ˆ¹5ì9rñÈ:(Š#yÃ‚Ÿ¹yê¨Y®¨S…>ŒFcœäÀâWQÆxmøsI­÷ž9ü½¡Î‡ÕœDš-tM"[û†²rkïÆ“IßÌÈUžÝbLõ}œ-fuHõî!æQS`¹üÖû2 [Ð¨.—(~ÀXø6›”ÅÀ£K¼­óŒÆ5Ä ÆÿÓH¶ã`ƒÙÂUó¼%+Ë€ÃÛl1c7áæš%¼èOÿ<¯ÃË|xwV}´ÈQ&ˆ(ózx––ïâ²çëzäj’¦sj:U37‹«V0*y£Ù/cõ°±*9åÔú‘’ŸÊþY_FŒš³ÝJÁÏ}Î~Î…ßÈµož)š—Bÿ…ÆN>œ[ê`ÖfŽê57sËËågÙÐ¼Ú‘Ôø°$o&DÂ¬XL³æèö<®Äµ‚9¶ÏÌ=n(6*ÿt?J%‚Ip¥B‹~q6ýø^·_ÓÍ:‹òµ„¬MKGŠÍ‰ñ‚ú5/=’2žj–ô–
```

I have no idea, what i will do to get text and match the  text with user input ?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I don't know what is in your PDF, but if you don't want people to have that data, I might take down the example you have above (starting with %PDF).

Comment: pdf has text,image, graph etc...

Comment: the code you have showed is same like OPENING AN MP3 FILE IN A NOTEPAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php

look to this..!

edit:

and http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php

are you try **[pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/developer/technical-documentation/manuals/)**

Answer (score 0):

A PDF is a structured and compressed file format containing a number of resources, such as plain text and binary data (images, fonts, etc.). Compression is optional. The main problem with attempting to pull text strings out of the PDF is that you don't know if the text structure was maintained during conversion. Some programs do a good job maintaining words/sentences as a string, while others may break things up in a way that makes the raw text from the PDF source unreadable. The source document and PDF rendering app matter in this case.

Before we get into the details of parsing text from a PDF you should just take a [quick look around the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+pdf2txt+function). Unless you want the experience there's no need to reinvent the wheel.