# Yii2: How to search inside PDF files?

Tags: php, pdf, full-text-search, yii2-advanced-app

I have some PDF files in the web folder of the Yii2 framework.

In the index.php I have a **input text field** where the user can enter a string that has to be find **inside** all the PDF files.

The PDF files has text.

I was thinking about some package for Yii2 at packagist.org or using PHP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506809/read-and-search-in-pdf-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read and search in pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506809/read-and-search-in-pdf-file)